# QtCreator template wizard: skipping dashes in %ProjectName% variable

Tags: xml, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to create a template wizard in which the project name (captured in the "New Project.." dialogs) is downcased and used to generate different things in C++ (a namespace, a library name, whatever..), so the generated names cannot contain dashes, begin with numbers, etc.

For instance, in wizard.xml, the variable `LIBRARYNAME` is generated from user input, BUT it takes a downcased `%ProjectName:l%` as default:

```
<fieldpagetitle>Project Configuration</fieldpagetitle>
    <fields>
    <!-- Library name -->
        <field mandatory="true" name="LIBRARYNAME">
            <fieldcontrol class="QLineEdit" validator='^[^-]+$'
                          defaulttext="%ProjectName:l%" />
            <fielddescription>Name for created library (all lowercase)</fielddescription>
        </field>
```

With the `validator = '^[^-]+$'` regexp thingy I can prevent users from introducing dashes ('-') in the variable BUT I can't prevent them doing the same when setting the `%ProjectName%` variable.

Is there any possible way of skipping undesired symbols in `%ProjectName%` and/or other variables used by the wizard? For instance when generating the `"defaulttext"` in the xml.

I have tried using different javascript-like things so far, but nothing worked and the docs on Template Wizards are too simple and they don't cover these things.

Right now my option is removing the default text in the forms, but that sucks!!! I want to do cool things like generating a namespace name from the project name.

Comment: what do you mean by "generating the "defaulttext" in the xml"?  you can use defaulttext="anyText" in xml

Comment: Of course I can, but I would like to use the %ProjectName% for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the normal validation rules not work with %ProjectName% variable?? Have you tried adding something like :

```
 <validationrules>
    <validationrule condition='/^[^-]+$/.test("%ProjectName%")'>
        <message>%ProjectName% cannot be used as project name.</message>
    </validationrule>
 </validationrules>
```

Comment: It works! but you have to remove the "!" or it invalidates all names that do not include dashes :D

Comment: Sorry, inverted that regex match by mistake.. :) my bad, corrected the answer

Comment: Your answer was not exactly what I was looking for, but then I realized that I can apply the same validation rules to %LIBRARYNAME% and other variables (the ones that cannot contain dashes). Anyway, with your regexp code I can do that now! Thank you!